# Extract rows between two static string rows in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with 2 columns in powerBi: Index and values. Values column contains a lot of rows in string format. Two of the rows in this column remain static all the time. I want to extract the rows data between these two staticrows. The index or the position of these static rows keeps changing with every new set of data.

Comment: Why do you need these rows extracted? What format do you need this data on? Should this happen after the data is loaded to the model or during data load? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a DAX solution that upon data refresh and persists a calculated table to the model that is filtered for the given `_string1` and `_string2` unique strings and returns the rows strictly between these.

```
Table Filtered = 
VAR _string1 = "Foo"
VAR _string2 = "Bar"
VAR _index1 = CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Index] ), 'Table'[Values] = _string1 )
VAR _index2 = CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Index] ), 'Table'[Values] = _string2 )
VAR _min = MIN ( _index1 , _index2 )
VAR _max = MAX ( _index1 , _index2 )
RETURN
FILTER ( 
    'Table' , 
    'Table'[Index] > _min && 'Table'[Index] < _max
)
```

It takes into account that the strings may not be in the same order every time, but if this can be guaranteed I am sure you are able to simplify the code accordingly.

As a rule, I cannot recommend persisting a new table containing largely what already exists in a table already. I would most likely be doing this in Power Query instead, a solution could look like this:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("NYwxCsAwDAP/4rmv6NBPmAyhsh26BOIs/X2LnUw6OEnMVB1QKgeTmkMtsCLC0RJkzDvg6j0LvhvLR+S4Qaf50uqpzpoprwzJC8G+etr/Wj4=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Values = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Values", type text}}),
    INPUT_TABLE = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    /*  These below steps form the actual solution */
        string1 = "Foo",
        string2 = "Bar",
        indexes = Table.SelectRows(INPUT_TABLE, each ([Values] = string1 or [Values] = string2))[Index],
        min_index = List.Min(indexes),
        max_index = List.Max(indexes),
        filtered = Table.SelectRows(INPUT_TABLE, each ([Index] > min_index and [Index] < max_index))
in 
    filtered
```

This will persist only a filtered table to your model. Since you have not stated anything about why you need this filtered list, I cannot give exact recommendations as to what would make more sense for your use case.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. It worked! Thanks for your simplified explantion.

Comment: Great to hear! Best of luck going forward!